# Hard to catch a vertex because of the gizmo

Tags: edit-mode, gizmo

Edit: Ok so it has been fixed by RJG, thanks to him, I had the same shortcut for select vertices and select gizmo, which seems the case by default? and I had to came back to right click for selecting vertices, which is perfectly fine to me.

---

I meet this very bad problem with 2.8. when the gizmo is displayed.

In *Object* mode it causes less problems, but when I switch to *Edit* mode and try to select a vertex close or even not so close to the gizmo, as if it seems like it's the same shortcut, Blender thinks I want to select and move the gizmo instead of the vertex, as if the gizmo was on a layer over the mesh, and not the opposite, which messes up a lot the work with the mesh, it makes you often move inadvertently some vertices.

In 2.7 it didn't work that way, because it was not the same keying for selecting vertex and selecting gizmo.

This doesn't seem logic nor convenient at all to me, it's even very bad   :/  Am I missing something like an option to activate?

In advance thanks for your answers...

[image]

Comment: Same behavior in a more or less current master build. However I don't find this particularly problematic because you can either just switch to select box or zoom in which will shrink the gizmo relative to the object size and the vertex can be selected without problems.

Comment: switch to select box or zoom in are not really solutions, on the contrary I find it very annoying   :((

Comment: Don't really catch the point? Are you left click select or something?

Comment: yes left click, is it not left clik for both selecting vertices and gizmo in 2.8?

Comment: @lemon Isn't left click is the new default?.  Been giving it a go atm.. takes some getting used to,   Have the issue with the gizmos.

Comment: @batFINGER !! left click select?? have you all became misbelievers?? ; )

Comment: In the beginning... I couldn't believe it was right click select, took a lot of getting used to. Surely we must believe in and follow the path recommended by the creators?

Comment: @batFINGER, yes surely, but they cleverly kept RCS... you know what, after a blender session, I still don't understand that other tools (gimp, or other, but also visual studio, why not) does not gives so simple and direct abilities that Blender gives. Surely once kept, this is the more efficient (far away to other tools). I hope Blender's creator won't forget that. To sum up my mind: Blender RCS and others, should become a standard. Others are misleading (whatever their popularity is).

Comment: It is what it is.  I am about 2 weeks into checking out LCS. Why? The abomination that is auto save settings took out my old 2.80 settings.  Thought I'd muddle thru default for the ... pain lol.  On solving the issue for LCS's  Maybe a swipy swipy mouse gesture disable  the gizmo make it disappear/// fade and pass thru events for some time frame?.  Gizmo code looks like a dark art.

Comment: ok it seems like I'm not the only one who think it's a very bad configuration, I hope they will fix it  :/

Comment: I'm currently not at my computer, so I can't test it, but perhaps this is the solution: https://twitter.com/YegorSmirnov_/status/1159588211963961346?s=19

Comment: Ooh yes fantastic, if fixes the conflict with the gizmo, please give my question the answer   ;)   now the world can collapse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit for the following answer goes to [Yegor Smirnov](https://twitter.com/YegorSmirnov_) who [tweeted about this](https://twitter.com/YegorSmirnov_/status/1159588211963961346?s=19).

The solution for this problem is to set the *Activate Gizmo* to *Drag* in *Keymap > Preferences*.

The tooltip explains what it does:

> Drag allows click events to pass through to the tool, adding a small
>   delay.

[image]

Comment: thank you been looking for this solution

Comment: @barkest You're welcome, but the credit goes to Yegor. I just stumbled upon his tweet by accident.

Comment: Thanks from me too.  While Left Click Select is default (_immaterial of whether one likes it or hates it_), certainly looks like making DRAG the default too, would remove a  conflicting default.  _In quick tests haven't noticed any undesirable side-effects_.